# Help me to find the value of $\frac{\sin^3(\theta)-\cos^3(\theta)}{\sin(\theta-\pi/4)}$ if $\sin(2\theta)=2\sqrt{2}-2$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the value of the expression
$$\frac{\sin^3(\theta)-\cos^3(\theta)}{\sin(\theta-\pi/4)}$$
if
$$\sin(2\theta)=2\sqrt{2}-2$$
I tried some approaches but none seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta}{\sin(\theta-\pi/4)}=\sqrt{2}\frac{(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)(\sin^2\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta)}{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}=\sqrt2(1+\frac12\sin2\theta)$$

Comment: I just don't understand $\sqrt{2}$ in front of the middle step. Can you please explain from where it comes from?

Comment: @Hanlon $\sin(\theta-\pi/4)=\sin\theta\cos\pi/4-\cos\theta\sin\pi/4$ and $\cos\pi/4=\sin\pi/4=\sqrt2/2=1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.